# Macro freezes when batch downloading attachments at around 500 files

Tags: vba, outlook, batch-processing

I'm using the macro below in outlook 2007 to download all the attachments from all the emails I have in a folder, but what keeps happening is that the process just freezes after 500 or so files have downloaded. Could this be a memory problem, if so how can I check?

I've tested it with less than 100 emails, the problem still persists, however now the process finishes successfully and the confirmation window displays the number of downloaded attachments, eg 1256, but in the output folder the item count is still 500. Tried it multiple times and it seems that I am unable to download more than 500 attachments. I'm guessing this is a different issue from what @niton sugested below as less than 250 items were opened.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    ' The window handle of Outlook.
    Private lHwnd As LongPtr

    ' /* API declarations. */
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

#Else
    ' The window handle of Outlook.
    Private lHwnd As Long

    ' /* API declarations. */
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If

' The class name of Outlook window.
Private Const olAppCLSN As String = "rctrl_renwnd32"
' Windows desktop - the virtual folder that is the root of the namespace.
Private Const CSIDL_DESKTOP = &H0
' Only return file system directories. If the user selects folders that are not part of the file system, the OK button is grayed.
Private Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = &H1
' Do not include network folders below the domain level in the dialog box's tree view control.
Private Const BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN = &H2
' The maximum length for a path is 260 characters.
Private Const MAX_PATH = 260

' ######################################################
'  Returns the number of attachements in the selection.
' ######################################################
Public Function SaveAttachmentsFromSelection() As Long
    Dim objFSO              As Object       ' Computer's file system object.
    Dim objShell            As Object       ' Windows Shell application object.
    Dim objFolder           As Object       ' The selected folder object from Browse for Folder dialog box.
    Dim objItem             As Object       ' A specific member of a Collection object either by position or by key.
    Dim selItems            As Selection    ' A collection of Outlook item objects in a folder.
    Dim atmt                As Attachment   ' A document or link to a document contained in an Outlook item.
    Dim strAtmtPath         As String       ' The full saving path of the attachment.
    Dim strAtmtFullName     As String       ' The full name of an attachment.
    Dim strAtmtName(1)      As String       ' strAtmtName(0): to save the name; strAtmtName(1): to save the file extension. They are separated by dot of an attachment file name.
    Dim strAtmtNameTemp     As String       ' To save a temporary attachment file name.
    Dim intDotPosition      As Integer      ' The dot position in an attachment name.
    Dim atmts               As Attachments  ' A set of Attachment objects that represent the attachments in an Outlook item.
    Dim lCountEachItem      As Long         ' The number of attachments in each Outlook item.
    Dim lCountAllItems      As Long         ' The number of attachments in all Outlook items.
    Dim strFolderPath       As String       ' The selected folder path.
    Dim blnIsEnd            As Boolean      ' End all code execution.
    Dim blnIsSave           As Boolean      ' Consider if it is need to save.

    blnIsEnd = False
    blnIsSave = False
    lCountAllItems = 0

    On Error Resume Next

    Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If Err.Number = 0 Then

        ' Get the handle of Outlook window.
        lHwnd = FindWindow(olAppCLSN, vbNullString)

        If lHwnd <> 0 Then

            ' /* Create a Shell application object to pop-up BrowseForFolder dialog box. */
            Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(lHwnd, "Select folder to save attachments:", _
                                                     BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS + BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN, CSIDL_DESKTOP)

            ' /* Failed to create the Shell application. */
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Run-time error '" & CStr(Err.Number) & " (0x" & CStr(Hex(Err.Number)) & ")':" & vbNewLine & _
                       Err.Description & ".", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
                blnIsEnd = True
                GoTo PROC_EXIT
            End If

            If objFolder Is Nothing Then
                strFolderPath = ""
                blnIsEnd = True
                GoTo PROC_EXIT
            Else
                strFolderPath = CGPath(objFolder.Self.Path)

                ' /* Go through each item in the selection. */
                For Each objItem In selItems
                    lCountEachItem = objItem.Attachments.Count

                    ' /* If the current item contains attachments. */
                    If lCountEachItem > 0 Then
                        Set atmts = objItem.Attachments

                        ' /* Go through each attachment in the current item. */
                        For Each atmt In atmts

                            ' Get the full name of the current attachment.
                            strAtmtFullName = atmt.FileName

                            ' Find the dot postion in atmtFullName.
                            intDotPosition = InStrRev(strAtmtFullName, ".")

                            ' Get the name.
                            strAtmtName(0) = Left$(strAtmtFullName, intDotPosition - 1)
                            ' Get the file extension.
                            strAtmtName(1) = Right$(strAtmtFullName, Len(strAtmtFullName) - intDotPosition)
                            ' Get the full saving path of the current attachment.
                            strAtmtPath = strFolderPath & atmt.FileName

                            ' /* If the length of the saving path is not larger than 260 characters.*/
                            If Len(strAtmtPath) <= MAX_PATH Then
                                ' True: This attachment can be saved.
                                blnIsSave = True

                                ' /* Loop until getting the file name which does not exist in the folder. */
                                Do While objFSO.FileExists(strAtmtPath)
                                    strAtmtNameTemp = strAtmtName(0) & _
                                                      Format(Now, "_mmddhhmmss") & _
                                                      Format(Timer * 1000 Mod 1000, "000")
                                    strAtmtPath = strFolderPath & strAtmtNameTemp & "." & strAtmtName(1)

                                    ' /* If the length of the saving path is over 260 characters.*/
                                    If Len(strAtmtPath) > MAX_PATH Then
                                        lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                                        ' False: This attachment cannot be saved.
                                        blnIsSave = False
                                        Exit Do
                                    End If
                                Loop

                                ' /* Save the current attachment if it is a valid file name. */
                                If blnIsSave Then atmt.SaveAsFile strAtmtPath
                            Else
                                lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If

                    ' Count the number of attachments in all Outlook items.
                    lCountAllItems = lCountAllItems + lCountEachItem
                Next
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Failed to get the handle of Outlook window!", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
            blnIsEnd = True
            GoTo PROC_EXIT
        End If

    ' /* For run-time error:
    '    The Explorer has been closed and cannot be used for further operations.
    '    Review your code and restart Outlook. */
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select an Outlook item at least.", vbExclamation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
        blnIsEnd = True
    End If

PROC_EXIT:
    SaveAttachmentsFromSelection = lCountAllItems

    ' /* Release memory. */
    If Not (objFSO Is Nothing) Then Set objFSO = Nothing
    If Not (objItem Is Nothing) Then Set objItem = Nothing
    If Not (selItems Is Nothing) Then Set selItems = Nothing
    If Not (atmt Is Nothing) Then Set atmt = Nothing
    If Not (atmts Is Nothing) Then Set atmts = Nothing

    ' /* End all code execution if the value of blnIsEnd is True. */
    If blnIsEnd Then End
End Function

' #####################
' Convert general path.
' #####################
Public Function CGPath(ByVal Path As String) As String
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
    CGPath = Path
End Function

' ######################################
' Run this macro for saving attachments.
' ######################################
Public Sub ExecuteSaving()
    Dim lNum As Long

    lNum = SaveAttachmentsFromSelection

    If lNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox CStr(lNum) & " attachment(s) was(were) saved successfully.", vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attachment(s) in the selected Outlook items.", vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try counting the number of items processed before failure. You may have run into a 250 item limit rather than a file limit.

[Outlook macro runs through 250 iterations before failing with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311774/outlook-macro-runs-through-250-iterations-before-failing-with-error)

[Sample Outlook macros to delete or move items in bulk](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2008840)

"When a macro is used to delete or move ... items, Outlook internally keeps the item “open” during the whole course of the macro’s lifetime. So for example, if you select and delete 100 items with the macro, Outlook will open 100 items “under the hood” and those items will not be closed until the macro finishes running. This design leads to a limitation of processing 250 items at a time for online mode profiles using a Microsoft Exchange Server account. By default, Exchange server limits MAPI clients to 250 open messages at one time. When using these macros or developing your own, note that you will only be able to select and operate on approximately 250 items at a time. This limitation is documented along with the information about re-configuring the limit in the following article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base: [Event ID 9646 is logged when you try to send many messages in Exchange Server 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830836)"

Comment: I've tested it with less than 100 emails, the problem still persists, however now the process finishes successfully and the confirmation window displays the number of downloaded attachments, eg 1256, but in the output folder the item count is still 500. Tried it multiple times and it seems that I am unable to download more than 500 attachments. I'm guessing this is a different issue as less than 250 items were opened.