# Mailmerge macro produces empty email after 200 emails created

Tags: vba, ms-word, outlook-2010

I've been playing with this macro for days now and when I thought it was working well I discovered that it works properly only with the first 200 emails. After that, it creates emails with proper recipient and subject, but no text and no attachments. After testing different scenarios, it seems that (some kind) of Outlook memory gets filled, but I don't know what and how to clear it ( i added oItem and oOutlookApp = nothing without success). The only way I can get it to work is if I close Outlook and run the macro again with the 200 and following emails. 
Any ideas?
thanks

EDITS:
1- I also tried clear the clipboard at the end of the loop using the accepted answer [overhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736915/how-to-clear-office-clipboard-with-vba), alas with no result.

2- I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311774/outlook-macro-runs-through-250-iterations-before-failing-with-error) that seems related to my problem. Two major differences though: my macro runs from Word to Outlook (not Outlook to Excel) and I don't get an error message; emails beyond #200 are simply created empty. So i don't know if/how it can be of help here.

3- Following niton's remark, there is now an error message. Progess I guess... [image: error message]

The highlighted line is

```
.Attachments.Add Trim(Datarange.Text), olByValue, 1
```

And it does that on the 200th email.

```
' MailMerge Macro
'
'
Sub MergeWithAttachments()
Dim Source As Document, Maillist As Document, TempDoc As Document
Dim Datarange As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim bStarted As Boolean
Dim oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim mysubject As String, message As String, title As String
Dim mailWord As Object
Dim oData As New DataObject


    Set Source = ActiveDocument
    ' Check if Outlook is running.  If it is not, start Outlook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        bStarted = True
    End If
' Open the catalog mailmerge document
    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
        .Show
    End With
    Set Maillist = ActiveDocument
    ' Show an input box asking the user for the subject to be inserted into the email messages
    message = "Enter the subject to be used for each email message."    ' Set prompt.
    title = "Email Subject Input"    ' Set title.
    ' Display message, title
    mysubject = InputBox(message, title)
' Iterate through the Sections of the Source document and the rows of the catalog mailmerge document,
' extracting the information to be included in each email.
If MsgBox("Are you adding cc email recipients?", vbYesNo, "CC email") = vbYes Then
    If MsgBox("Are your cc email recipients in the second column from the left?", vbYesNo, "CC in second column") = vbYes Then
        GoTo Add_cc
        Else:
        If MsgBox("Cc email recipients need to be in the second column. Please rework your directory accordingly.", vbOKOnly, "Cancelling Mail Merge") = vbOK Then
        Exit Sub
        End If
No_cc:

For j = 1 To Source.Sections.Count - 1

    Source.Sections(j).Range.Copy
    Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set mailWord = oItem.GetInspector.WordEditor

    With oItem
        .Subject = mysubject
        mailWord.Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
        Set Datarange = Maillist.Tables(1).Cell(j, 1).Range
        Datarange.End = Datarange.End - 1
        .To = Datarange
        For i = 2 To Maillist.Tables(1).Columns.Count
            Set Datarange = Maillist.Tables(1).Cell(j, i).Range
            Datarange.End = Datarange.End - 1
            .Attachments.Add Trim(Datarange.Text), olByValue, 1
        Next i
        .Send
    End With
    Set oItem = Nothing
Next j

GoTo Merge_finished

Add_cc:
For j = 1 To Source.Sections.Count - 1

    Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With oItem
        .Subject = mysubject
        Set Datarange = Maillist.Tables(1).Cell(j, 1).Range
        Datarange.End = Datarange.End - 1
        .To = Datarange
        'code for adding cc emails. Currenlty set to read column 2 as cc emails
        Set Datarange = Maillist.Tables(1).Cell(j, 2).Range
        Datarange.End = Datarange.End - 1
        .CC = Datarange.Text
        Source.Sections(j).Range.Copy
        Set mailWord = oItem.GetInspector.WordEditor
        mailWord.Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

        For i = 2 To Maillist.Tables(1).Columns.Count
            Set Datarange = Maillist.Tables(1).Cell(j, i).Range
            Datarange.End = Datarange.End - 1
            .Attachments.Add Trim(Datarange.Text), olByValue, 1
        Next i
        .Send
        End With
    Set oItem = Nothing

Next j

Merge_finished:
End If
Else: GoTo No_cc
End If

Maillist.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
'  Close Outlook if it was started by this macro.
If bStarted Then
    oOutlookApp.Quit
End If
MsgBox Source.Sections.Count - 1 & " messages have been sent."
'Clean up
Set oOutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the word document? Why do you have `Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` in your second loop? I don't think you need that, remove it. I also see your adding a lots of data to the clipboard, make sure to clear it to avoid errors

Comment: Put an On Error Goto 0 just after Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application"). There should always be an On Error Goto 0 as soon a the On Error Resume Next is no longer needed.

Comment: @Om3r - can't share the word document beacause it contains email addresses. And besides, I've narrowed down the problem to be with Outlook, not Word or the Clipboard. I've added the oOoutloopApp thing when I was tired and desperatly trying anything! Will remove it!

Comment: @niton - I'll do that but I doubt it will solve the problem I have as this piece is just to open Outlook if it's not opened already (I think).

Comment: I don't mean the real data, just add fake data

Comment: @Pomul  "There should always be an On Error Goto 0 as soon a the On Error Resume Next is no longer needed." The problems, if any, are hidden when you do not turn off the On Error Resume Next. Now if there is an error message you will get to see it so you can fix it. Always have an On Error Goto 0 when there is an On Error Resume Next.

Comment: @niton - I now get an error message. see edit.

Comment: @Pomul  It is progress in your VBA programming knowledge. You know debugging is impossible without the matching On Error Goto 0. I was a little hasty the On Error Goto 0 should be just before ' Open the catalog mailmerge document.  1) What line is highlighted? 2) Did you get to 200?

Comment: Ah, I see. The On Error Resume Next is good until cancelled kind of thing! The highlighted line is `.Attachments.Add Trim(Datarange.Text), olByValue, 1` And it does that on the 200th email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be running into this. [Outlook macro runs through 250 iterations before failing with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311774/outlook-macro-runs-through-250-iterations-before-failing-with-error)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830836

"This issue occurs because of a limit on the number of items that clients can open. By default, this limit is set to 100 for attachments and 250 for messages."

Your limit could be set to 200. If you cannot fix this, if the cause, try changing your code. Mark processed items or moving them, with a down counting loop starting at 200. Close Outlook after 200 items are processed. Reopen and process the remainder 200 at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, niton.